# Can someone help me fix the poor typography here?

Tags: align

I do not like to just ask others to do it for me but I have been stuck on this for a while now trying to experiment with different things. At the end, I just ended up using hspace and manual spaces and I think this makes the equation split weirdly. If anyone could help me fix how the equations look with the align function, I would greatly appreciate it. By fix, I just mean to make the equations break automatically so that there is no imprecision because currently I am breaking it manually. If that is not possible, any better option would be great.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{article}

\usepackage[left=0.5in, right=0.5in, top=0.5in, bottom=0.5in]{geometry}


\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{cancel}
\usepackage{caption}

\counterwithin{equation}{section}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\urlstyle{same}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{physics}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{nccmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amsfonts, amssymb}
\usepackage{physics}

\allowdisplaybreaks

\linespread{1.9}

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}



\usepackage{etoolbox}
\newcommand{\zerodisplayskips}{%
  \setlength{\abovedisplayskip}{6pt}%
  \setlength{\belowdisplayskip}{6pt}%
  \setlength{\abovedisplayshortskip}{6pt}%
  \setlength{\belowdisplayshortskip}{6pt}}
\appto{\normalsize}{\zerodisplayskips}
\appto{\small}{\zerodisplayskips}
\appto{\footnotesize}{\zerodisplayskips}
\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
\dv{}{x} f(x) ={}& {}- 1.0839\times10^{-5}x^{4} + 2.09472\times10^{-4}x^{3} + 6.6279\times 10^{-3}x^{2} - 0.161606x + 0.59776\\[10pt]
SA\,_{\textnormal{curve,actual}} ={}& 2\pi \int_{a}^{b} f(x)\sqrt{1+\left( f'(x)\right)^{2}} \,dx\\[12pt]
\begin{split}
\hspace{0.15cm}={}&2\pi \int_{0}^{21} \Bigg[\Bigg.\bigg(- 2.1678\times10^{-6}x^{5} + 5.2368\times10^{-5}x^{4} + 2.2093\times 10^{-3}x^{3}\\
    &\hspace{2cm}-8.0803\times 10^{-2}x^{2} + 0.59776x + 2.5227\bigg)\bigg(1+({}- 1.0839\times10^{-5}x^{4}\\ 
    &\hspace{2cm} + 2.09472\times10^{-4}x^{3} + 6.6279\times 10^{-3}x^{2} - 0.161606x + 0.59776)^{2}\bigg)^{\frac{1}{2}}\Bigg. \Bigg]\,dx\\
\hspace{0.15cm}\approx{}&351\ \textnormal{cm}^{2}
\end{split}
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use `aligned` within the integral so the brokn terms stay aligned without needing hspace on each row. Never use `\big` always use `\bigl` and `\bigr` (but `\big.` does nothing useful, it just adds horizontal space)  You can use the standard `&=`form here rather than `={}&`

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{article}

\usepackage[left=0.5in, right=0.5in, top=0.5in, bottom=0.5in]{geometry}


\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{cancel}
\usepackage{caption}

\counterwithin{equation}{section}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\urlstyle{same}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{physics}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{nccmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amsfonts, amssymb}
\usepackage{physics}

\allowdisplaybreaks

% are you sure you want this,
% it makes the math very spaced out so hard to avoid "bad typography"
\linespread{1.9} 

% similarly this, no parindent and no parskip means paragraphs
% paragraohs are not marked
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}



\usepackage{etoolbox}
\newcommand{\zerodisplayskips}{%
  \setlength{\abovedisplayskip}{6pt}%
  \setlength{\belowdisplayskip}{6pt}%
  \setlength{\abovedisplayshortskip}{6pt}%
  \setlength{\belowdisplayshortskip}{6pt}}
\appto{\normalsize}{\zerodisplayskips}
\appto{\small}{\zerodisplayskips}
\appto{\footnotesize}{\zerodisplayskips}
\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
\dv{}{x} f(x) &= {}- 1.0839\times10^{-5}x^{4} + 2.09472\times10^{-4}x^{3} + 6.6279\times 10^{-3}x^{2} - 0.161606x + 0.59776\\
\mathit{SA}_{\mathrm{curve},\mathrm{actual}} &= 2\pi \int_{a}^{b} f(x)\sqrt{1+( f'(x))^{2}} \,dx\\
&=2\pi \int_{0}^{21} \Bigl(
\begin{aligned}[t]
&(- 2.1678\times10^{-6}x^{5} + 5.2368\times10^{-5}x^{4} + 2.2093\times 10^{-3}x^{3}\\
&    -8.0803\times 10^{-2}x^{2} + 0.59776x + 2.5227)(1+({}- 1.0839\times10^{-5}x^{4}\\ 
&    + 2.09472\times10^{-4}x^{3} + 6.6279\times 10^{-3}x^{2} - 0.161606x + 0.59776)^{2}
)^{\frac{1}{2}} \Bigr)\,dx
\end{aligned}\\
&\approx 351\,\mathrm{cm}^{2}
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```